# Creating a PHP hit counter for many webpages without database?

Tags: php, hitcounter

I know I can create a PHP counter using files like this

```
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('count.txt');
echo $hit_count;
$hit_count++;
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count);
```

I don't want to create a new file for every webpage and I want to avoid using databases. How should I proceed?

Comment: You could have one file with a row for every page. Read the file in, increment the counter for the current file, then write bit back out. Make sure you lock the file to prevent problems with multiple scripts running at the same time.

Comment: So, I will have a new line for every webpage?

Comment: Yeah. Or you could store it as an array using `json_encode` or `serialize`.

Comment: I assume you want a separate hit counter for each page, not just one for the whole site.

Comment: Yes, I want a separate hit counter. Is there some tutorial or link to any article that can guide me because I have never done this before.

Comment: I don't know. I'd use google to find it, why don't you?

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything about hit counters, since they'll probably show how to do it using a database. Why are you doing it the hard way if you don't know how?

Comment: Beware that you might get in trouble if you try to do multiple writes to a single file. (You can use (flock)[http://php.net/flock] for that but as was already said - why do it the hard and not really reliable way. If your webhosting does not allow you to do so, okay then. But in any other case, you should definitely give DB a try.)

Comment: I would make a simple file counter and configure it to use a different file per website. You can make a directory called 'counters' and store the files with the same name as the domain name/website/page name the counter is for.